# ¿Cómo usar helper asset de laravel en una etiqueta `html`?

Tags: laravel

Tengo una duda, quisiera saber como podría resolver el uso del `helper asset` de laravel si es que se puede para lo siguiente:

```
<li style="background-image: url(images/servicio-de-armado-de-muebles.jpg);">
```

¿Conocen alguna alternativa?

Saludos!

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: hola, creo lo mas fácil seria ponerle una clase y rutear la imagen desde la hoja de css, pero quería saber si se puede usar la asset como con la src o el href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes usar un **helper** de Laravel, el que se emplea para este caso es el `asset()` que se encarga de buscar los recursos contenidos en la carpeta /public donde puedes acceder también a otras sub carpetas como: 
/imagenes
/css
/js
/fuentes

Sintaxis:

```
{{ asset('ruta y archivo en public') }}
```

Entonces tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
<li style="background-image: url({{ asset('images/servicio-de-armado-de-muebles.jpg') }});">
```